# Does $x^T A x \geq \min \{\mathrm{Re}(\lambda(A))\} x^T x$ holds for non-symmetric positive definite $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Tags: matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a non-symmetric positive definite matrix and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. That means $\forall x \neq 0$, $x^T A x > 0$. Does the following hold?

$$x^T A x \geq \min \{\mathrm{Re}(\lambda(A))\} x^T x$$

Thanks very much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are your use cases of non-symmetric positive definite matrices?

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your question. It refers to that $x^T A x \geq 0$ and $x^T A x = 0$ iff $x = 0$.

Comment: I know your definition. I am asking about what are the uses of non-symmetric positive definite matrices.

Comment: @user1551 It is employed in the control of multi-agent systems, where the interactions are modeled as graphs. Since we consider directed graphs, the corresponding Laplacian matrices are non-symmetric. As the convergence analysis is based on constructing a Lyapunov function, we need something like $x^T A x$, where we also need some additional requirements as presented in this question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This type of statements can be easily refuted through a counterexample. Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$

then $x^TAx=x_1x_2$ but $\min\Re(\lambda(A))=0$, which is a counterexample since $x_1x_2$ can be negative. Another immediate counterexample is when the matrix only has non-real eigenvalues as in such a case, the inequality sign does mean much.

Now let us prove the correct lower bound. Note that we have that $$x^TAx=\dfrac{1}{2}x^T(A^T+A)x$$ since $x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx$. As a result, we have that

$$x^TAx\ge\dfrac{1}{2}\min\Re(\lambda(A+A^T))x^Tx.$$

Taking back the example yields $$A+A^T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

which is $1$ and $-1$ as eigenvalues, which yields the lower bound $x^TAx\ge-1/2 x^Tx$. This can be verified to be equivalent to $x_1x_2\ge -(x_1^2+x_2^2)/2$. Equivalently, $(x_1+x_2)^2\ge0$, which is obviously true and tight whenever $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. What if the matrix $A$ is positive definite, i.e., all the eigenvalues of $A$ always have positive real parts?

Comment: @Ryan The bound I gave applies to all possible cases. Just substitute a matrix in there and see what happens. Pick $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -6\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1\\-1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ , for instance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments. Yes, the bound is perfect which holds for any square matrix. The main idea is to convert a matrix (corresponding to a quadratic form) to a symmetric one (w.r.t. the same quadratic form). But is there any bound directly related to $A$ rather than $A + A^T$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ryan No, there is no such bound except in very particular cases.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts of $A$ by $S$ and $K$ respectively, so that $S$ is symmetric positive definite. You are essentially asking whether
$$
\lambda_\min(S)\ge\min_i\operatorname{Re}\lambda_i(S+K).\tag{1}
$$
In general, no, because the **reverse** inequality holds. In fact, if $x$ is a unit eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, then
$$
\lambda_i=x^\ast Ax=x^\ast Sx+x^\ast Kx.
$$
Since $K$ is real skew-symmetric, $x^\ast Kx$ is purely imaginary. Therefore $\operatorname{Re}\lambda_i=x^\ast Sx\ge\lambda_\min(S)$. Since this is true for every eigenvalue of $A$, we conclude that
$$
\lambda_\min(S)\le\min_i\operatorname{Re}\lambda_i(S+K).
$$
It follows that $(1)$ holds if and only if equality holds. This occurs precisely when an eigenvector $x$ corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $S$ is also an eigenvector of $A$. In other words, it occurs precisely when $Kx=0$. In particular, $(1)$ never holds if $K$ is non-singular.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! [+1] Dividing $A$ into the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts is a great idea! I have carefully read this answer and understood most of the parts. But "This occurs precisely when an eigenvector $x$ corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $S$ is also an eigenvector of $A$" is still not clear to me. Could you please provide more details? Thanks so much!